# Density plot in ggplot2 using log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to use ggplot2 density geometry using a log transformation for the x scale:

```
qplot(rating, data=movies, geom="density", log="x")
```

This, however, produces a chart with probabilities larger than 1. One solution that seems to work is to scale the dataset before calling qplot:

```
qplot(rating, data=transform(movies, rating=log(rating))
```

But then the x axis doesn't look nice. What is the correct way to handle this?

---

It seems that my question doesn't not, in fact, make sense. It seems that it is OK that probability densities are larger than one, as per [[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-is-ok)]. What is important is that the integral over the entire space is equal to one [[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the right answer.

```
qplot(rating, y = ..scaled.., data=movies, geom="density", log="x")
```

stat_density produces new values, one of them is ..scaled.. which is the density scaled from 0 to 1.
[image: example plot]

HTH